# PyGame in MacOSX: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0

Tags: python, pygame, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawimage

I've recently started using PyGame to develop a simple program that shows an image but I ran into a problem where I can't load images with a lot of colour (?). During my first tests I was using some ground truth segmentation images, so it was all black and two colours delining the segmented portion of the image. When I tried drawing the real image, it would show up a black image and the following error in terminal:

```
Oct 24 00:50:08  python[4371] <Error>: CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: CGColorSpace does't support output
Oct 24 00:50:08  python[4371] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

I've tried searching around the Internet for people that have ran into this problem but all I could find is people having the invalid context problem on XCode (which I'm not using).

For the sake of it, here's the simple code I wrote, no mystery:

```
    import pygame
    import glob
    import os

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))

    imageName = '2.png'
    myimage = pygame.image.load(imageName)
    imagerect = myimage.get_rect()


    while 1:
        screen.fill((255,0,255))
        screen.blit(myimage, imagerect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)
```

I'm running Python 2.7.12, OSX 10.12 Sierra and PyGame 1.9.2.

Edit: I just tried with a PNG file that's all black and the same errors occurs. I don't know what is going on.

Edit 2: I tried running PyGame example code that loads a PNG file and displays it (pygame.examples.scaletest) and the same error happens, so I'm guessing it's a Sierra update problem.

Comment: The code you posted works for me on Sierra using python 2.7.12 installed from brew, combined with `sudo python -m pip install pygame` and `brew install libpng`

Comment: @user2588654 What image you tried using on it? Only a few pictures work for me, maybe you got lucky. I've already updated my python. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it with [this](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/graphics/python/newlogo-repro.png) python logo online image and it worked. Maybe provide a link to an image that is failing for you and I can test it out. Also, have you tried calling `pygame.image.load(imageName).convert()` or `.convert_alpha()`  instead? Not sure if that would help but it does improve blit performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Sierra.
My solution was to uninstall and reinstall PyGame.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to uninstalling pygame, I also had to uninstall the following:

`brew uninstall sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf smpeg portmidi`

Then reinstall:

`brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf smpeg portmidi`

Then after:

`python -m pip install pygame`

It started working again.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me :) Was having issues with logstalgia rendering the colored balls that represents requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in Sierra for python3.

- First, I upgraded from 3.5 to 3.6.1.
- Second, I downgrade the pygame.
- Uninstall pip3 uninstall pygame ==> Uninstall 1.9.4
- Install pip3 install pygame ==> Install 1.9.3